# What is the red .gradle file in android studio 1.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated my Android Studio to v1.2. Now I see a folder named ".gradle" marked red. It does not produce any errors but I wonder whether it indicates something is wrong. So, why is this folder marked red?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means folder is **excluded**. See settings -> directories, or press RMB over this folder and look at "Mark directory as" menu item.

Answer (score 2):

usually red means that the directory/file is not under version/source control, e.g. it has not been yet added to git. You can check the meaning in the Android Studio preferences, in the File Status tab

Answer (score 1):

Those are harmless files that Gradle uses mainly for in-memory caching. For example `fileSnapshots.bin`, helps with the change detection Gradle uses to speed up builds and not recreate items that haven't been modified.

If you're curious, you can see the [source for the InMemoryTaskArtifactCache on Github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/changedetection/state/InMemoryTaskArtifactCache.java).

Answer (score 0):

May be do you have some Conflit to Fix